# Why should we use THE in these cases?

Tags: articles, definite-article

```
An apple a day keeps the doctor away.
Curiosity killed the cat.
```

I try to learn the articles but I can't get these cases. Why should say `the doctor` instead of `a doctor` and same is about `the cat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you are in the emergency room of a large metropolitan hospital where there are many physicians on duty. You can say

> I am waiting to be seen by **a** doctor.
>
> I am waiting to be seen by **the** doctor.

The choice of article reveals how you are thinking of it:

a doctor = one of the many physicians who are here

the doctor = the physician (*whoever it turns out to be*) who will be assigned to my case, the one who comes into examination room where I am waiting.

In much the same way, you can say:

> An apple a day keeps **the** doctor away.

Which doctor? No doctor in particular, but the one you will have to see if you should become ill.

Now, let's say there is a fable about a fox who wants to eat some grapes. We can refer to the fable as

> The story of **the** fox and **the** grapes

Which fox?  *The fox who figures in the fable*. The fox who wanted to eat some grapes.

Which grapes?  *The grapes which figure in the fable*. The grapes the fox wanted to eat but could not reach.

In much the same way, we can say

> Curiosity killed **the** cat.

Which cat?  The cat in the proverbial example that we should bear in mind.